# PHP Session and Cookie error in my Admin login page

Tags: php, mysql, session-cookies

I am working on Admin login page using PHP and MySQL. I am using XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2 and Chrome browser.

I have used `session` and `cookie` in my admin login page but I have found following error

```
Notice: Undefined index: nam in C:\xampp\htdocs\online_voting\admin\index.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: pas in C:\xampp\htdocs\online_voting\admin\index.php on line 4
```

in my `index.php` page.

I can not find out cause of this error. What might be the problem?

This is my MySQL database connection page.

#### connection.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('poll') or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

### For Login :

`Email : admin@gmail.com
Password : admin`

#### Database name is `poll` and table name is `tbadministrators` .

```
-- Table structure for table `tbadministrators`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbadministrators` (
  `admin_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`admin_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbadministrators`
--

INSERT INTO `tbadministrators` (`admin_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES
(1, 'Md. Rezwanul', 'Haque', 'admin@gmail.com', '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3');

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

I have used following pages for admin login .

#### index.php

```
<?php
      session_start();
      $myusername = $_SESSION['nam'] ;
      $mypassword = $_SESSION['pas'] ;
?>
<?php
      if(isset($_COOKIE['$email']) && $_COOKIE['$pass']){
          header("Location:admin.php");
          exit;
      }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Admin Login Form</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900|RobotoDraft:400,100,300,500,700,900'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

      <script language="JavaScript" src="js/admin.js">
  </script>


</head>

<body style="background-image:url('images/demo/backgrounds/bCY7Scu.png');">




<div class="pen-title">
  <h1>Admin Login Form</h1>
</div>

<div class="container" >
  <div class="card"></div>

  <div class="card">
    <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
    <form name="form1" action="checklogin.php" method="post" onsubmit="return loginValidate(this)">

      <div class="input-container">
        <input name="myusername" value="<?php echo $myusername  ?>" type="text" required="required"/>
        <label>Email</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-container">
        <input name="mypassword" value="<?php echo $mypassword ?>" type="password"  required="required"/>
        <label>Password</label>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>

      <center><tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> <font color="blue">Remember Me</font></td></tr></center><br>

      <div class="button-container">

        <button name="Submit"><span>Login</span></button>

      </div>
      <br><br>
    <center>Return to <a href="http://localhost/online_voting/index.php">Voter Panel</a></center>

    </form>
  </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

#### checklogin.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">


<?php
//session_start();
ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

ob_start();
session_start();
require('../connection.php');

$tbl_name="tbAdministrators"; // Table name


/*
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
$encrypted_mypassword=md5($mypassword); 

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
*/

$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
$encrypted_mypassword=md5($mypassword); 

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$myusername' and password='$encrypted_mypassword'" or die(mysql_error());
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


if($count==1){
    // If everything checks out, you will now be forwarded to admin.php
     // $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
     // $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $user['admin_id'];
    // header("location:admin.php");



                if(isset($_POST['remember']))
                {
                    setcookie('$email',$_POST['myusername'], time()+30*24*60*60);
                    setcookie('$pass', $_POST['mypassword'],time()+30*24*60*60);
                    $_SESSION['curname']=$myusername;
                    $_SESSION['curpass']=$mypassword;

                    $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $user['admin_id'];

                    header("Location:admin.php");
                    exit;
                }
                else
                {
                    $log1=11;
                    $_SESSION['log1'] = $log1;
                    $_SESSION['curname']=$myusername;
                    $_SESSION['curpass']=$mypassword;

                    $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $user['admin_id'];

                    header("Location:admin.php");
                    exit;
                }


}
//If the username or password is wrong, you will receive this message below.
else {
    echo "<br> <br> <br> ";
    echo "<center> <h3>Wrong Username or Password<br><br>Return to <a href=\"index.php\">login</a> </h3></center>";
}

ob_end_flush();

?> 




</body>
</html>
```

#### admin.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require('../connection.php');
    $log1 = $_SESSION['log1'];
?>
<?php
      if(isset($_COOKIE['$email']) && $_COOKIE['$pass']){
            $curnam = $_SESSION['curname'];
            $curpas = $_SESSION['curpass'];
        }
        else if($log1 == 11)
        {
            $curnam = $_SESSION['curname'];
            $curpas = $_SESSION['curpass'];
        }
        else 
        {
           echo '<img src="e1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"  />';  /* here goes the page when destroy the cookies */
           exit;
        }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>online voting</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<link href="layout/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<script language="JavaScript" src="js/user.js">
</script>

</head>
<body id="top">
<div class="wrapper bgded overlay" style="background-image:url('images/demo/backgrounds/background1.jpg');">
  <section id="testimonials" class="hoc container clear"> 

    <h2 class="font-x3 uppercase btmspace-80 underlined"> Online <a href="#">Voting</a></h2>
    <ul class="nospace group">

       <li class="one_third">

          <blockquote>In this page, Admin can set candidates for voting and view results.</blockquote>

      </li> 

    </ul>

  </section>
</div>
<!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.backtotop.js"></script>
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
<!-- IE9 Placeholder Support -->
<script src="layout/scripts/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
<!-- / IE9 Placeholder Support -->
</body>
</html>
```

#### logout.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  //session_destroy();
  /*header("location: index.php");
  exit;*/
  if( isset($_COOKIE['$email']) and isset($_COOKIE['$pass'])){
      setcookie('$email',' ',time()-30*24*60*60);
      setcookie('$pass',' ',time()-30*24*60*60);
      $nam=$_COOKIE['$email'];
      $pas=$_COOKIE['$pass'];
      $_SESSION['nam'] = $nam;
      $_SESSION['pas'] = $pas;
      header("location: index.php");
      exit;
  }
  else
  {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
  }
?>
```

[PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

From their solutions could not help me properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: This question is not duplicate above questons. I have tried to solve this error from their  solutions. But their solution could not help me. -  B. Desai

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a uselessly weak hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Thanks all . :) I have solved my error properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first time visit the page at that time your value not set in session. So you have to check first if value is set or not then assign the value. Change the following in **index.php**:

```
<?php
      session_start();
      $myusername = isset($_SESSION['nam'])?$_SESSION['nam']:"" ;
      $mypassword = isset($_SESSION['pas'])?$_SESSION['pas']:"" ;
?>
```